# Bluetooth is always off, even when switched on

Tags: bluetooth, raspberrypi

I’m running the new Raspberry Pi 400 with Ubuntu 20.10 and the Bluetooth won’t come on even when I toggle it on in the settings. (The rocker switch is active, but it still says “Bluetooth turned off” underneath.)

I’ve tried doing a fresh install and also managed to pair my Bluetooth headphones while running Raspberry Pi OS, so I don’t think there’s anything wrong with the hardware

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

There's currently a bug in Bluez causing this issue on the Pi400, and a fix is currently being worked out and SRUd (hopefully soon).  There's a couple pi 400 specific workarounds we need to land into bluez itself

Comment: I'm getting the same problem on my Dell XPS 13, is there a fix for this yet?