# Is there a specific ticket/issue number for error with network adapter on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS?

Tags: networking, wireless, bluetooth

This is my first question on AskUbuntu so please don't eat me alive :D

So I came across this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290277/bluetooth-is-always-off-even-when-switched-on) and it seems like there's an error with network adapter on Ubuntu 20.04.2 causing Bluetooth and/or WiFi problems (in my case only one of them can work :| ). I was wondering if one could monitor this issue somehow and track the bugfix (or verify the answer to the question)? Where are such problems reported?

BR,
Andreas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).  We do not take bug reports on Ask Ubuntu. Please file it appropriately so that it can be triaged.

Comment: This is a Ubuntu user support site (specifically a Q&A site; the forum is elsewhere), but the page you referenced was for a different release (Ubuntu 20.10; or the first release post-20.04 that is working towards 22.04 or the next LTS) so not all the software *stack* may apply with your *focal* release (though 20.04 if using the HWE stack did use the 20.10 stack - but that's history now as a *focal* system will now be using the *hirsute* stack as 20.04.3 is out; https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/08/27/ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-released/ showing ISO release date - installed system upgraded before then)

Comment: Bugs are tracked on a bug tracker (*not user support sites*), ie. https://launchpad.net/ for Ubuntu ; however for `bluez` or the package referenced in your page that mentions bug - it may not apply as the package version doesn't match - refer https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=bluez&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all  Bugs can be tracked (for bluez) via https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bugs  with fixes for *focal* https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/b/bluez/bluez_5.53-0ubuntu3.3/changelog

Comment: If there is a bug report, its number has not been provided, but you can easily search for it with keywords like "Raspberry Pi 400 ubuntu bluetooth bug".

Answer (score 0):

This is a Ubuntu user support site (*specifically a Q&A site; the forum is elsewhere*), but the page you referenced was for a different release (Ubuntu 20.10 or *groovy*; or the first release post-20.04 that is working towards 22.04 or the next LTS) so not all the software *stack* may apply with your *focal* release (though 20.04 if using the HWE stack did use the 20.10 stack - but that's history now as a *focal* system will now be using the *hirsute* stack as 20.04.3 is out; https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/08/27/ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-released/ showing ISO release date - installed system upgraded before then)

Bugs are tracked on a bug tracker (*not user support sites*), ie. https://launchpad.net/ for Ubuntu.

Also for `bluez` or the package referenced in your page that mentions bug - it may not apply as the package version doesn't match, refer

- https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=bluez&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Bugs can be tracked (for bluez)

- via https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bugs

with fixes for *focal*  see

- https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/b/bluez/bluez_5.53-0ubuntu3.3/changelog

Comment: Also note:  security issues are usually back-ported to older releases; some issues only get fixed on later releases; eg. for bluez you can compare to fixes in a later release, ie. contrast the post I gave with a later version - https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/b/bluez/bluez_5.60-0ubuntu2/changelog (it'll have same security fixes; but other non-security fixes as well)